# SQL syntax error near '' at line 14

Tags: mysql, syntax, triggers, phpmyadmin, heidisql

I have created this trigger in HeidiSQL IDE for mysql trough IDE´s helper and it worked pretty good. If I copy the create code generated by the IDE and try to run it on phpmyadmin I get a SQL syntax error that I just can´t figure how to fix it. Can anyone help me?

```
CREATE TRIGGER `teste` AFTER UPDATE ON `ilmug_virtuemart_products` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
   IF (NEW.origem_sync <> 0) THEN 
      INSERT INTO sincronizar (dataHora,
                               tipoMovimento,
                               entidade,
                               id,
                               version,
                               STATUS) 
                       VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),
                  'update',
                  'virtuemart_products',
                   NEW.virtuemart_product_id,
                   NEW.version,
                  'pendente');
   END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a `BEGIN` statement...but the `END` is missing

---

Since you have edited your question, I tested it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0ebbf

According to sqlfiddle, there is *no* syntax error...

Comment: This is not the problem, i´ve tried many different types of syntax. My problem is that the query runs on the IDE but does not run on command or phpmyadmin. I´ve updated the query, check again and tell me if you se anything wrong.

Comment: Even without syntax error I still get this erros on phpmyadmin:
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 14

Answer (score 0):

Use `DELIMITER`.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `teste` AFTER UPDATE ON `ilmug_virtuemart_products` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   IF (NEW.origem_sync <> 0) THEN 
      INSERT INTO sincronizar (dataHora,
                               tipoMovimento,
                               entidade,
                               id,
                               version,
                               STATUS) 
                       VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),
                  'update',
                  'virtuemart_products',
                   NEW.virtuemart_product_id,
                   NEW.version,
                  'pendente');
   END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Then perhaps you should consider marking the answer as accepted, along with all the correct answer to the other questions you have asked.